# peer probe: failed: Probe returned with Transport endpoint is not connacted

Tags: centos7, glusterfs

I want to create 2 server glusterfs but I don't know why when I run command `gluster peer probe server1` they have error. Firewalld is active.

```
# gluster peer probe server1
peer probe: fail: Probe returned with Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the problem is with the firewall, you should be able to open the firewall ports with the following command:

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=<zone_name> --add-service=glusterfs [--permanent]
```

You might want to test first if disabling the firewall works, and then tune the firewall rules and services for your environment.